# You must call removeview on the child parent first. Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I got a problem with opening spinner. When i open it first time it opens correctly and lets me choose from it. Then when i try to open it second time it gives me an error:

```
11-21 18:43:49.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3178): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

My spinner opens on click on ImageButton. Here the code:

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
    final Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ImageButton bracket = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    bracket.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    choosed_bracket = (String) sp.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sp.setAdapter(adp);

            builder.setTitle("Choose war bracket:");
            builder.setView(sp);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    /*SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("bracket", choosed_bracket);
                    editor.commit(); */
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choosed bracket is: " + choosed_bracket, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
```

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to instantiate your builder inside the onclick event instead outside?

```
 ImageButton bracket = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    bracket.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(arg0.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
            Spinner sp = new Spinner(arg0.getContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext());
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    choosed_bracket = (String) sp.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sp.setAdapter(adp);

            builder.setTitle("Choose war bracket:");
            builder.setView(sp);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    /*SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("bracket", choosed_bracket);
                    editor.commit(); */
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choosed bracket is: " + choosed_bracket, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```